# calling a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I made a function to validate an email and I would like to know how I would go about calling it so that it can work. I'm also trying to use ajax along with php.

my jquery code

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

$("#sub").click(function(){
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
            $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
            function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
        }); 


});

$("#myForm").submit( function(){
    return false;
});

function clearInput(){
    $("#myForm :input").each( function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

index.php

```
    <form id="myForm" action="ajax/userInfo.php" method="post">
<input class="required" type="text" name="email" id="email">
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" id="sub">
<form>
```

userInfo.php

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
global $_NEWSLETTER_CUSTOMERS_TABLE;

//$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = html_entity_decode(str_replace("'", "\'", $_POST["email"]));

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO $_NEWSLETTER_CUSTOMERS_TABLE(email) VALUES('$email')"))
echo "Successfully Inserted";
else
echo "Insertion Failed";
```

Comment: where is your email input element

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#sub").click(function () {
    var $form = $("#myForm");
    if (!isValidEmailAddress($form.find('input[name="email"]').val())) {
        alert('enter valid email')
        //if the validation fails return
        return false;
    }
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.find(":input").serializeArray(), function (info) {
        //give the proper email fields name here
        $("#result").html(info);
    });
});

function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

$("#myForm").submit(function () {
    return false;
});

function clearInput() {
    //no need to loop
    $("#myForm :input").val('');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bFS66/)

Comment: Thank you Arun, that was what I needed :-D